# C memcpy behaves differently on Linux and Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, memory, gcc

Okay, first of all a description of my problem. I have a sample program, only one file. The only included headers are part of the standard library. For training and testing I wrote my own `malloc` wrapper which automatically writes 0 to the entire storage block. On my Netbook (Debian + Gnome Desktop, raw gcc call like this: `gcc memstest.c -o memstest`) it runs without problems. The check for any other data then 0 is successful, even though I removed the entire iterative check for each part of the storage due to benchmarking. When trying this on Windows with Code::Blocks as IDE and GNU gcc compiler configured, it tells me that there is data within the allocated storage (most times a value of -60). As seen, I'm mostly only using unsigned values, therefore it shouldn't be possible that this value is a failure of mine when writing it to the data block. I guess it's the `memcpy` functions, since it's the only routine that touches this data block. If I'm mistaken, I will change the topic title.

Here'a my sample Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <time.h>

void *Smalloc_dyn( unsigned int n_bytes );

int main( void )
{
    time_t start_t, end_t;
    double difference;
    unsigned int index = 0;
    start_t = time( NULL );
    for( index = 0; index < 10000000; index++ )
    {
        char *test = Smalloc_dyn( 65536 );
        if( *test != 0 )
        {
            printf( "Found data without 0 overwriting...\n" );
            return 0;
        }
        free( test );
    }
    end_t = time( NULL );
    difference = difftime( end_t, start_t );
    printf( "Smalloc_dyn took %.1fs\n", difference );
    start_t = time( NULL );
    for( index = 0; index < 10000000; index++ )
    {
        char *test = calloc( ( 65535 / sizeof( (long) 0 ) ), ( 65536 / ( 65535 / sizeof( (long) 0 ) ) ) );
        if( *test != 0 )
        {
            printf( "Found data without 0 overwrting...(2)\n" );
            return 0;
        }
        free( test );
    }
    end_t = time( NULL );
    difference = difftime( end_t, start_t );
    printf( "calloc took %.1fs\n", difference );
    return 0;
}

void *Smalloc_dyn( unsigned int n_bytes )
{
    /*
    This fusion of malloc and a modified memset
    is way faster than calling malloc() and
    after that memset( *dst, 0, len(dst) ).
    We are defining 0 as a long and will
    therefore copy ( for example ) 8 Bytes
    instead of a per-byte copying.
    With a memory need of 1024, we only
    have 128 steps instead of 1024.
    */
    if( 0 == n_bytes )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    long unsigned int chr = 0;
    unsigned int steps = sizeof( chr ) / n_bytes;
    unsigned int asteps = n_bytes % sizeof( chr );
    unsigned int index = 0;
    char *mem_ptr = malloc( n_bytes );
    if( NULL == mem_ptr )
    {
        return mem_ptr;
    }
    char *write_ptr = mem_ptr;
    for( index = 0; index < steps; index++ )
    {
        memcpy( write_ptr, &chr, sizeof( chr ) );
        write_ptr = write_ptr + sizeof( chr );
    }
    for( index = 0; index < asteps; index++ )
    {
        memcpy( write_ptr, &chr, 1 );
        write_ptr = write_ptr + 1;
    }
    return mem_ptr;
}
```

Edit: Corrected Code

Comment: So you realize sizeof(chr)/n_bytes is going to be zero, right? Integer 4/65536 is 0. Also asteps is 0 as well, as 65536 % 4 is 0. So you're never calling memset at all. Perhaps that's why it's "way faster" :)

Comment: Thats again one of that examples of 'Can't see the forest due to to much trees'. I was looking for an value error of some sort. Okay, again a nice lesson to reread own code more then just 2 times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the value of `steps` evaluated as

```
unsigned int steps = sizeof( chr ) / n_bytes;
```

and not as

```
unsigned int steps = n_bytes / sizeof( chr );
```

?

This looks like a potential source for the problem, since most of the allocated block will be left uninitialized due to this error. In "most" cases `steps` will end up being zero (like in your test case with `nbytes` being `65536`). Unintialized data can easily "behave" differently between platforms.

Comment: In this test program, both steps and asteps are 0, so memset isn't called even once.

Comment: Oh my ... Okay thanks guys. So just a type of mine. I will delete this topic after a while to keep this clean. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @fairiestoy: Deleting the question takes away the points awarded to AndreyT for the upvote and accept. Just leave the question as it is; if others decide it's not useful, they might vote to close and/or delete it.